# Get Validation error messages in controls

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, devexpress

I am using C# to build a windows form with DevExpress. In the windows form I have DXValidationProvider and DXErrorProvider to show error message for invalid cases. We try to use localization for error messages. My question, how to check if the windows form has DXValidationProvider and how to check which contorls are defined in the DXValidationProvider. We tried to use the following code

```
foreach (Control item in Controls)
{
    if (item is DXValidationProvider)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

We got warning as shown in the below picture

[image]

Comment: [DXValidationProvider](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.DXValidationProvider) is a [Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and will not appear in `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 2):

[DXValidationProvider](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.DXValidationProvider) is a [Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and will not appear in `Controls` collection.

If you have added the component through designer, then there should be a `components` member in your form. You can use it like this:

```
var provider = components.Components.OfType<DXValidationProvider>().FirstOrDefault();
if(provider != null)
{
    //do something ...
}
```

Comment: Your code has been placed in the constructor, but the provider is null. any suggestion? Should I move it to be in form_load?

Comment: To give it a try, for example use it inside a click event handler of a button. When you made it working, put it in the correct place (You should make sure the code is after `InitializeComponent`.)

Comment: definitely, it's after  InitializeComponent, will try to handle it in click event.